# Optional fields in creating a SP site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

i'm creating a SP site and i have one field that is optional which is '$SecondaryAlias', i would like the script to create the site even if the secondaryAlias variable is empty but instead it's giving me the following error:

```
New-SPSite : Cannot bind parameter 'SecondaryOwnerAlias'. Cannot convert value "" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPUserPipeBind". Error: "Value cannot be null.
```

this is my secondaryAlias script block and i'm not so sure how to manipulate it correctly:

```
Do{
$SecondaryAlias = Read-Host 'Optional: SecondaryOwnerAlias'


try {
  $user = get-aduser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$SecondaryAlias' -OR name -eq '$SecondaryAlias'"
}
catch {
  "no secondaryOwnerAlias has been chosen"
   break
}

   Do{
If (!$user) {
  "The user does not exist in AD" 
   break
} 
Else {
  "The user does exist in AD:`nsamaccountname: $($user.samaccountname)`nFull Name: $($user.name)"

}
}While (($null -eq $SiteOwnerAlias) -or ( "" -eq $SiteOwnerAlias)) 
}until ($user) 

New-SPSite -Url $siteUrl -name $sitename  -Language $SiteLanguage -Template $SiteTemplate -OwnerAlias $SiteOwner -SecondaryOwnerAlias $SecondaryAlias
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to have the SecondaryAlies in another `if/else` condition like the below:

```
If($SecondaryAlias)
{
    New-SPSite -Url $siteUrl -name $sitename  -Language $SiteLanguage -Template $SiteTemplate -OwnerAlias $SiteOwner -SecondaryOwnerAlias $SecondaryAlias
}
else
{
    New-SPSite -Url $siteUrl -name $sitename  -Language $SiteLanguage -Template $SiteTemplate -OwnerAlias $SiteOwner
}
```

Hope it will do the trick you are looking for.

PS: I am not checking the other logics; only answered your specific logic issue.

Comment: @Dutta so simple but i just didn't think of it!! thank you !

Comment: @user11124311: happy to help. That's how we learn. Enjoy Coding :).